How to Exclude Specific Columns in Oracle APEX Interactive Grid Flashback?
I am working with Oracle APEX and using an Interactive Grid with Flashback functionality enabled. One of the columns in my grid is a query-only column (it is calculated using an SQL query and does not exist in the underlying table).
When I attempt to use Flashback, I encounter this issue:
The Flashback operation fails with an "Insufficient Privileges" error.
If I remove the query-only column from the grid, the Flashback works fine and the record is returned as expected.
I believe this issue occurs because the specified column is a computed column and not part of the underlying table, causing the Flashback to fail.
How can I exclude certain query-only columns from being considered in the Flashback functionality of an Interactive Grid in Oracle APEX?
Is there a way to conditionally include or exclude such columns only during Flashback operations?
Removing the column completely from the grid (this resolves the issue but is not ideal since the column is needed in the UI).
Searched for a setting in APEX to exclude specific columns from Flashback but couldn't find one.

I don't think it's feasable to "exclude" certain columns. What you can do is run the page in debug mode. In de debug you'll see what the sql statement is that is executed by the APEX engine and that is raising the error. That can give you ideas on how to modify the source query so it works with flashback
